# Javascript performance issue using javascript.php instead of javascript.js

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any performance issue using

```
<script src='javascript.php'></script> //.php
```

Instead of

```
<script src='javascript.js'></script> //.js
```

javascript.php (need it to access session value)

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>

$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: <?php echo $_SESSION['value'] ?>
    });

   // ... more javascript ...
```

Comment: is it bad practice? yes. is that more important than performance? yes.

Comment: I'd assume your server is slightly faster in serving a static file (`.js`) than a file it has to parse first (`.php`). You could compare this by trying both versions and having a look at Chrome's DevTools network tab.

Comment: the right way to do it: replace dynamic JS code with input parameters (function arguments). put those input parameters (the configuration) in the dynamically generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a performance issue, but not for the reason you might expect. It's true that it takes a fraction of a second longer to parse a PHP file than to serve a static JS file, but the real killer is that you can't cache the PHP file because it contains a changing variable. The client has to download the file again and again every time.

The "right" way to do it is to set the JavaScript variable in the HTML file.

```
<script>
    var session = <?php echo json_encode( $_SESSION[ 'value' ] ); ?>; 
</script>

<script src='javascript.js'></script>
```

javascript.js:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: session
    });
```

Now the script file can be safely cached as it's guaranteed to have static contents.

A matter of opinion, but even "more right" way would be to pull any dynamic values from the server using AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version will be slower because you have to run PHP on the server to produce the Javascript.

There won't be any performance difference on the client. It doesn't care how the JS was created, it's just text.